# How to make tsung-recorder capture websocket messages?

Tags: websocket, erlang, stress-testing, tsung, tsung-recorder

My website uses websockets, and I'd like to conduct load testing using tsung.

I start tsung-recorder and configure proxy setting (only HTTP for now)

When a user opens a page it switches protocols. I understand that websockets work over TCP, nevertheless first handshake request are made over HTTP.

I see neither handshake nor websocket requests in tsung-recorder.xml. As expected only HTTP requests are there.

What should I do to get correct session written, including handshake and websocket requests?

Comment: I've got a question for you: can you run a server on localhost:4000 when using tsung?  That would mean that in the config file the `hostname` for both the `<client>` and `<server>` would be `"localhost"`.

Comment: @7stud, I do not fully understand what is your question about. Neither my website should not be installed and started locally, nor tsung-recorder. I am just using proxy (which is to say, recorder) to visit website (wherever it is) from my browser

Comment: I was just asking you a question for my own education--not trying to figure out what you are doing.  When I do `tsung-recorder start` then navigate to a page being served up on localhost:4000, then login, which takes me to another page, then do `tsung-recorder stop` the only thing that ends up in the file is `</session>`.  Have you ever seen that problem?

Comment: @7stud, first of all you should set your http proxy settings to `localhost:8090`, then keep in mind that chrome by default exclude proxy settings for `localhost`. Cheat it! Write `mywebsite.local` to /etc/hosts pointing to 127.0.0.1